# Lidgdx Java Sprite falling

Tags: java, android-studio

I was not sure how to title this article. I am making a game that has sprite falling down. I already have triangles falling down in my game. I don't  know how to change it where images that I import in the game that allows the image falling.

Icicle:

```
package com.udacity.gamedev.icicles;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Icicle {

    public static final String TAG = Icicle.class.getName();

    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;

    public Icicle(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = new Vector2();
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        velocity.mulAdd(Constants.ICICLES_ACCELERATION, delta);
        position.mulAdd(velocity, delta);
    }

    public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.triangle(
                position.x, position.y,
                position.x - Constants.ICICLES_WIDTH / 2, position.y + Constants.ICICLES_HEIGHT,
                position.x + Constants.ICICLES_WIDTH / 2, position.y + Constants.ICICLES_HEIGHT
        );
    }
}
```

Icicles:

```
package com.udacity.gamedev.icicles;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.DelayedRemovalArray;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.udacity.gamedev.icicles.Constants.Difficulty;


public class Icicles {

    public static final String TAG = Icicles.class.getName();

    Difficulty difficulty;

    int iciclesDodged;
    DelayedRemovalArray<Icicle> icicleList;
    Viewport viewport;

    public Icicles(Viewport viewport, Difficulty difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.viewport = viewport;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        icicleList = new DelayedRemovalArray<Icicle>(false, 100);
        iciclesDodged = 0;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        if (MathUtils.random() < delta * difficulty.spawnRate) {
            Vector2 newIciclePosition = new Vector2(
                    MathUtils.random() * viewport.getWorldWidth(),
                    viewport.getWorldHeight()
            );
            Icicle newIcicle = new Icicle(newIciclePosition);
            icicleList.add(newIcicle);
        }

        for (Icicle icicle : icicleList) {
            icicle.update(delta);
        }

        icicleList.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < icicleList.size; i++) {
            if (icicleList.get(i).position.y < -Constants.ICICLES_HEIGHT) {
                iciclesDodged += 1;
                icicleList.removeIndex(i);
            }
        }
        icicleList.end();
    }

    public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.setColor(Constants.ICICLE_COLOR);
        for (Icicle icicle : icicleList) {
            icicle.render(renderer);
        }
    }
```

}

Constant:

```
package com.udacity.gamedev.icicles;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public static final float ICICLES_HEIGHT = 1.0f;
    public static final float ICICLES_WIDTH = 0.5f;
    public static final Vector2 ICICLES_ACCELERATION = new Vector2(0,-5.0f);
    public static final Color ICICLE_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
```